# Estimating population proportions when resamplling

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion, resampling

I'm learning statistics and thought this would be a good exercise with real incomplete data but I'm  bit stuck.

The following is an excerpt from the latest Australian COVID-19 Epidemiology Report,

> :There have been 1,765 confirmed cases, including seven deaths,
>   reported in Australia as at 23:59 AEDT 22 March 2020 Hospitalisation
>   status was recorded for 717 cases, of which 26% (n = 190) were
>   reported to have been hospitalised due to their COVID-19 infection. Of
>   these hospitalised cases, ICU (Intensive Care Unit) status was
>   recorded for 87 cases, of which 20% (n = 17) were admitted to an
>   ICU, with two cases requiring ventilation;"

If I assume my population to be the 1,765 confirmed cases, and treat the reported hospitalisations (717) as a sample, then knowing that 26% of the sample were hospitalised, I think I can use confidence intervals to estimate the proportion of hospitalisations of the entire population of positive cases (assuming of course the sample was randomised which I acknowledge may be a flawed assumption).

Using the formula for a population proportion confidence interval of a finite population $CI = \hat p \pm z \times \sqrt{\frac {\hat p(1-\hat p)}n} \times \sqrt{\frac {N-n}{N-1}}$

and using a 95% confidence level I get $CI = 0.26 \pm 1.96 \times \sqrt{\frac {0.26(1-0.26)}{717}} \times \sqrt{\frac {1765-717}{1765-1}} = 0.26 \pm 0.0247$

So, for the total population of positive cases there is estimated 23.53-28.47% hospitalisations within a 95% confidence level.

I'd like to be able to make a similar estimation for the percentage of ICU cases and ventilator cases however I'm unsure if the same method would be valid because the ICU/ventilator cases are a resampling of the hospitalisation sample. Can the same method be used with $n=87$? I don't think I can make the same randomised assumption about the resample, those 87 cases depend on being selected in the original sample.

Hope this makes sense, and I've posted in the correct forum (first time).

Edit: 
Actually, I think that even estimating the hospitalisation percentage of the population is invalid because of the 10% condition (sample needs to be no more than 10% of the actual population, and here it is 40.6%).

Since the population proportion confidence interval method cannot be used there, are there any alternatives? Potentially you could take the population to be all the untested but positive cases but that doesn't help estimating the proportions in the tested group.